# How would i use PIL to pixelate an image?

Tags: python

i tried to use pillow to pixalte an image, i can get the average r ,b ,and g values and have  been able to set the image to an average color or pixelate it 1x1, how would i pixelate it by with more pixels, i cant find a code space efficent of soing this, i know that it has smething to do with breaking the image into a grid

```
from PIL import Image

size = (200, 200)
actual = Image.open('My image')
red = []
blue = []
green = []`enter code here`

og = actual.resize(size)
pop = og.load()

for y in range(40):
    for x in range(40):

        cow = pop[x, y]
        red.append(cow[0])
        blue.append(cow[1])
        green.append(cow[2])

for y in range(og.size[1]):
    for x in range(og.size[0]):
        pop[x, y] = (cow[0], cow[1], cow[2])

y = sum(red) // len(red)
z = sum(blue) // len(blue)
t = sum(green) // len(green)

og.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can pixelate with Pillow.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageStat

size = (200, 200)
actual = Image.open('/path/to/your/image.png')

og = actual.resize(size)

output = Image.new('RGB',(200,200))

tile_width = 5
for i in range(0,200,tile_width):
    for j in range(0,200,tile_width):
        box = (i,j,i+tile_width,j+tile_width)
        region = og.crop(box)
        median = ImageStat.Stat(region).median
        r = Image.new('RGB',(tile_width,tile_width),tuple(median))
        output.paste(r,(i,j))

output.show()
```

Please note that other methods exist for choosing the color of each tile.

Comment: what does this line do ?"median = ImageStat.Stat(region).median"

Comment: It compute the median color of the tile.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to just use [PIL.Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) function:

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('./dumpster/Mario_org.jpg')

org_size = im.size
pixelate_lvl = 8

# scale it down
im = im.resize(
    size=(org_size[0] // pixelate_lvl, org_size[1] // pixelate_lvl),
    resample=0)
# and scale it up to get pixelate effect
im = im.resize(org_size, resample=0)
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]